# Cómo hago para ver el output de var_dump (Array) Bien en el navegador? Ami se me ve todo pegado y mal

Tags: php, array, variables, google-chrome, navegador-web

Esta pregunta es un poco más sobre extension y navegador,

Estoy siguiendo un curso de Victor Robles, y cúando hace Var_dump a el se le ve el objeto bien estructurado y no como amí:
[image: Var dump mal estrcturado..]

Me gustaría como puedo hacer para que se me vea como a otras personas, no se si es mediante alguna extension o configuracion del navegador.

A el se le ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si sabeis de alguna forma os lo agradecería mucho, ya que cuando el output son de varios objetos se vuelve muy tedioso..... Me pasa tanto con arrays como con objetos.

Comment: Puedes poner esto antes del `var_dump`: **`echo "<pre>";`**  y luego poner esto: **`echo "</pre>";`**, así verás la salida identada.

Comment: Ese es el resultado de `var_dump()` cuando tienes instalado [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/develop#display)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes poner esto antes del `var_dump`: **`echo "<pre>";`**  y luego poner esto: **`echo "</pre>";`**, así verás la salida identada.

Algo así:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($loQueSea);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Si saldra con var_dump, y no necesariamente con `<pre>`, lo que tienes que hacer es configurar el servidor y agregar el xdebug, en mi caso tengo wamp server, y en el apartado PHP/Configuracion de PHP activa el que dice xdebug_show_locals_vars, algo asi. Pero activando eso te mostrara todo chevere